# What "echo !T " do?

Tags: bash

I don't know how many of you have encountered this, but I find it interesting. Maybe also because I do not totally know what the "echo" command can do. If anyone has the interest and nerves to give me a couple of reasons for this I would be most grateful.

Playing is learning and I must ask you to check with your terminal first: 
What is the output of the command `echo !T` in your terminal?

Here is what the terminal shows me as an output:

```
echo They are 9 in the fellowship
They are 9 in the fellowship
```

The terminal I am playing with is using the default bash shell, on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. What does "!T" stand for in the "echo" command?

Comment: This is a [Q&A site](http://askubuntu.com/about). What are you actually asking?

Comment: I forgot to stress the question, thank you for pointing that out :)

Comment: No, I listed everything. No matter which is the directory I work in, the output is the same. And this is what I found quite intriguing :-?? ...and awesome as I recently watched LOTR :))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`!T` is not related to `echo` but is replaced by bash before `echo` can see it.

A `!` that is not followed by a white space character or `=` starts history substitution. That is it gets replaced with the most recent command in the hostory list that starts with what follows the `!`.

So `!T` gets replaced with the most recent command you entered that starts with a `T`.

`echo` then just outputs that.

Comment: Tried it and it makes sense x_X ...though I did not know about that :|
Thank you!

Comment: Note that the sequence `!!` gets replaced with the last command entered. This is especially useful when you forgot to use sudo, just type `sudo !!` to run last command with superuser privileges. (Could be used to avoid repetition, for example: https://www.xkcd.com/149/)

Answer (score -2):

While you are learning/playing in cli (command line interface), you can use man  to get a synopsis of what the command is and what options are available. Basically, echo just outputs text to the screen. I have seen it used to pipe (|) data into/from files.
Good luck!

Comment: I have quite some material to cover until piping. I looked over the man page of echo, but none seem to suggest such thing :| Normally I think the output of "echo !T" should actually be "!T". Have you tried it and ran as expected?

Comment: I get the following: bash: !T: event not found. So, apparently the !T is a variable set in your environment.

Comment: One thing you could do is start a new terminal session and run the command. If you get the output from above then most likely you set T to that string in the other session; otherwise the T variable is being set in your user preferences.

Comment: Closed and started Terminal several times. Could you introduce me into the world of clearing its history? :))

Comment: If you closed/open then you started a new session. CTRL-Shift-T is a new tab (like FF), CTRL-SHIFT-N creates a new session. So, I'm guessing its something in your user profile and/or environment. You can type env to see your environment settings

Comment: @Nooby the bash history is stored in your home folder.  It is hidden so you will need to `Ctrl+H` to see it, the file is `.bash_history`.  You can click on it and delete the file. or from a terminal you can use `rm .bash_history` (`rm` is remove, if you use the -v switch it will show you all the files that were deleted- `rm -v .bash_history`)  removing that file will remove all the terminal history of that user so that the up arrow will not be able to scroll back in the history.  there is not any reason to remove this file, it will not grow to large it only stores the last 30 or so commands)